# Bluetooth Process is Dying constantly

Tags: bluetooth, lineageos, development

My phone's bluetooth keeps disconnecting and connecting constantly.
I recently built my first custom ROM, Lineage OS 20 for my Redmi Note 9 (Merlin/Merlinx). Lineage OS is not officially supported on my device, so I used the community maintained device tree from [here](https://github.com/mt6768-dev).
The build went smoothly and my phone is running just fine on it. BUT I'm facing this issue bluetooth. I ran adb logcat and in the logs I found this particular line:

> Process com.android.bluetooth (pid 3034) has died: psvc PER

I don't know how to fix this. I am a complete newbie at rom development. Any insight into this would be highly appreciated. I am attaching the full 1-min long log in the [pastebin](https://pastebin.mozilla.org/PP8SDbwH). Please ask for any more info if needed. Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Please note that ROM development is off-topic since Android Enthusiasts focuses on end-users and power users (who are not necessarily developers) solving their issues. Thus, while this community might explain the technicality of Android OS to your queries, coding solutions are out of the scope of this community.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your phone in Selinux Permissive mode and check Bluetooth and if it does work it's just some denials you will have to address:)

I saw your trees and you have the required props for Bluetooth to work on Android 13.